# session variable not displaying in view in Ci?

Tags: codeigniter

This my controller body which contains the session variable place tell me how to use session variable in view

```
$username=$this->input->post('username');
                $password=md5($this->input->post('password'));
                $user_id=$this->user_model->login($username,$password);
                if($user_id){
                    $user_data=array(
                    'user_id'=>$user_id,
                    'username'=>$username,
                    'usertype'=>$usertype,
                    'logged_in'=>true
                );
```

its not Working

```
 <?php  echo $this->session->userdata('usertype');  ?>
```

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you enable `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` first on your autoload.php and set the session variable then echo on your `View`

Answer (score 0):

First **update your autoload.php** as below. Otherwise it will not work in CI.

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

Change your controller into this:

```
$username=$this->input->post('username');
    $password= md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $user_id=$this->user_model->login($username,$password);
    if($user_id)
    {
       $user_data=array(
        'user_id'=>$user_id,
        'username'=>$username,
        'usertype'=>$usertype,
        'logged_in'=>true
        );
     }

$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
```

**To get all session data in view:**

```
$this->session->all_userdata();
```

**To get single session data:**

```
$usertype= $this->session->userdata('usertype');
```

You can have a better idea from this:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh if this answer helped you could you please give an up vote for my answer.